# Magento - For "Manage Categories" Forbidden You do not have permission to access this document

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, error, backend

i have this problem about "Manage Categories" in backend of my Magento 1.7 and 1.9. Now when i go in menu --> manage categories i see white page with only this message:

```
Forbidden
You do not have permission to access this document.

The Web Server
```

What is the problem? I try to edit .htaccess but without success...the problem may be a missing file?

Thank you very much for any help

Errors from system.log

```
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for lessc::setFormatter(), called in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/local/Sns/Toronto/Helper/Data.php on line 150 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1948
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1949
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 91 of 894 bytes  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 8
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 10
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for lessc::setFormatter(), called in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/local/Sns/Toronto/Helper/Data.php on line 150 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1948
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1949
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 91 of 894 bytes  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 8
2016-05-03T10:06:51+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 10
2016-05-03T10:06:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for lessc::setFormatter(), called in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/code/local/Sns/Toronto/Helper/Data.php on line 150 and defined  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1948
2016-05-03T10:06:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: name  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/page/sns/lessc.inc.php on line 1949
2016-05-03T10:06:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 91 of 894 bytes  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 8
2016-05-03T10:06:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in /var/www/vhosts/higift.it/httpdocs/upgrade/app/design/frontend/sns_toronto/default/template/sns/blocks/sticky.phtml on line 10
```

Comment: did you tried it by re login and accessing it?

Comment: check the server (apache error log) error log and paste it here

Comment: Ok man, i edit the post with errors of system.log

Comment: Did you checked you have right permission for all folders and files?

Comment: Anyone updated the httpd conf file on your server recently? Maybe someone has altered the allow deny settings there.

Comment: And to control this, where should I go?

Comment: Do you have webserver access?

Comment: Yes man, i can check right permission from webserver access?

Comment: I read of this code for fix 403 error Forbidden, is right? find ./ -type f | xargs chmod 644
find ./ -type d | xargs chmod 755
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media

Comment: can you check by disabling `Sns_Toronto` extension